# How to get the exact year from date of birth?

Tags: javascript, math

how do you get the age from 6 characters?

(API giving me only this value: 16010119951, to find the age, first 6 characters are yymmdd. How do I know 16 is: 2016 or 1916 or 1816? )

```
function get_age(input) {

  var y = input.charAt(0) + input.charAt(1);
  var m = input.charAt(2) + input.charAt(3);
  var d = input.charAt(4) + input.charAt(5);

  y = parseInt(y);
  m = parseInt(m);
  d = parseInt(d);

  if(m<10) { m = '0' + m; }
  if(d<10) { d = '0' + d; }
  var ymd = d + '-' + m + '-' + y;

  return ymd;
}
```

Comment: Your question about "does 16 mean 1816, 1916 or 2016" isn't one that can be answered by code. If the API really will give you the same value for all those three years, then you can't differentiate between them.

Comment: Do you have any more information in your input to validate the year yourself?

Comment: Is the value perhaps a unix timestamp? This one resolves to `Tue, 04 May 2477 07:32:31 GMT`. Also, omg, it's Jon Skeet.

Comment: OK - i assume that its design mistake by the API. Cause the project contain historic age, so a person can have 1816 or newly born 2016. Thank you